# How do I start a JPA transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have some code in a class in my Java server project (Spring/JPA based). This code is not associated with any kind of a managed entity like a RestController or a Service. It also does not run on the main thread (it is started by a Quartz job).

Within this code I need to update a JPA entity. If I try to do this without a transaction, I get a TransactionRequiredException.

Of course, I cannot create a transaction using the @Transactional annotation which is what the rest of the code in this project uses.

I see some examples of using an EntityManager to get a transaction, with the EntityManager itself gotten from an EntityManagerFactory which in turn comes from Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(). But there is a problem: this function requires a parameter called "persistenceUnitName". I do not know what the persistence unit name is.

I did not create this project. The developers who did are long gone, so it's up to me to figure it out.

I'm reading that the unit name is supposed to be set in a file called persistence.xml, but there is no such file in my project.

I believe that the original developers of this project used annotations as much as possible and avoided config files. I looked around for some annotation that looks like it might be defining a unit name, but I can't find it.

Where should I look for this name? Is it possible that it isn't being set? Is there a default value? Is this even the right way to go about getting the transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find your persistence-unit name in your `persistence.xml`, usually located in `src\main\resources\META-INF`. Should match the name of your database.

Comment: I ended up making a new function in the JpaRepository and annotating that function with @Transactional, this was an easy solution.